# how to convert character into hexdecimal with proper format?

Tags: java, swing, char, jtextarea, hex

I converted characters into hexadecimal format But it looks ugly how to provide the formatted way.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you know how to write good questions? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my question is not duplicated and i updated my code also and remove the question as duplicated.@StanislavL

Comment: you have a simple formatting issue - it's not a problem with conversion... maybe you can ask a new question or ask if the Administrator helps you out to redisgn your question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Answer (score 0):

something like this could help:

```
char ch = 'a';
String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) ch);
tf.setText(hex);
```